# Best way to manipulate variables inside a JSON config file in Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, config

I want to have a JSON config file where I can reference values ​​internally. For example, consider this JSON config file at bellow:

```
{
  "hdfs-base":"/user/SOME_HDFS_USER/SOME_PROJECT"
 ,"incoming-path":"$hdfs-base/incoming"
 ,"processing-path":"$hdfs-base/processing"
 ,"processed-path":"$hdfs-base/processed"
}
```

The main idea is to leverage values already stored in *json* object. In this case, replacing '$hdfs-base' to 'hdfs-base' attribute's value. Do you know something that do that already? I don't wanna use *ConfigParser* module because I want to use JSON.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your values, and substitute the keys if there's a match:

```
import json

js = open('input.json').read()
data = json.loads(js)

for k, v in data.items():
  for key in data.keys():
    if key in v:
      data[k] = v.replace("$" + key, data[key])
```

**BEFORE**

```
hdfs-base /user/SOME_HDFS_USER/SOME_PROJECT
incoming-path $hdfs-base/incoming
processing-path $hdfs-base/processing
processed-path $hdfs-base/processed
```

**AFTER**

```
hdfs-base /user/SOME_HDFS_USER/SOME_PROJECT
incoming-path /user/SOME_HDFS_USER/SOME_PROJECT/incoming
processing-path /user/SOME_HDFS_USER/SOME_PROJECT/processing
processed-path /user/SOME_HDFS_USER/SOME_PROJECT/processed
```

REPL: https://repl.it/repls/NumbMammothTelephone

Comment: I've already wrote a similar code. But I was wondering about recursion in  all hierarchy. This code works just at the first hierarchical level ! Probably I'm not beeing so clear about it. Sorry! Thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: This is very brittle code; if you have keys `a` and `any`, you can end up matching `$a` as part of the `"$any"`. You also need to worry about indeterminacies in the substitution order; if a replacement string contains variables, you won't necessarily get a chance to expand them. This is not a trivial thing to do, and OP is right to be looking for a solid implementation.